# How to set order of cipher suites for Jetty SSL?

Tags: java, ssl, jetty

For serving my application I use Apache or embedded Jetty. For Jetty I selected some cipher suits I want to use and set it using `setIncludeCipherSuites(String[] names)`. On Jetty documentation (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/CipherSuites) I have found that: *Be aware that you must specify cipher suites in preference order.*

But SSL Report by https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ report that:

```
Cipher Suites (sorted by strength; the server has no preference)
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)    ECDH 571 bits (eq. 15360 bits RSA)   FS   128
(3 other suites I use)
```

For Apache I got:

```
Cipher Suites (SSL 3+ suites in server-preferred order, then SSL 2 suites where used)
```

It seems that for Jetty order in which I set items in `setIncludeCipherSuites()` has no meaning. Is there any way to set order of preferred cipher suites?

Answer (score -1):

The best answer I have found is to use Apache HTTPD as a reverse proxy in front of the Jetty server and use OpenSSL to set the cipher suite priority there. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20849587/70465).

Comment: This is not an answer. At best, it should be a comment.